# How disable documentation generation for the base class in doxygen?

Tags: c++, doxygen

Let's assume I have the following class definition:

```
/// \brief My Cat class
class Cat : public Animal {};
```

When I want to generate the doxygen documentation, I get the following:

```
1. Class Animal

2. Class Cat
My Cat class.
```

Is there a way to generate only the following:

```
1. Class Cat
My Cat class.
```

Comment: Which version of doxygen are you using. Maybe a `@cond` / `@endcond` comment around the `Animal` class could work. Best is always to post a small complete example showing the problem (together with the changes in respect to the default doxygen configuration file).

Comment: @albert That solved my issue. You can post it as an answer.